# Cloning a worksheet through Google Spreadsheet API (php)

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-sheets-api

I am creating a front end for google spreadsheet using the zend library and php. Instead of creating a new worksheet from scratch and putting in all the headings, which takes time, is it possible to clone an existing worksheet in the spreadsheet (ie use a template worksheet that then be populated with my frontend), which would save time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so cloning a worksheet is not possible - however, I did work out a way around it to speed up the process of creating a worksheet, which is a clone of one already made (let's call this worksheet A).

If you define the ranges for the fixed values (ie column headers, row headers) in worksheet A, then when it comes to creating the worksheet via the api - use the formula for insert range and update the cell where you would like the range to start